# Gamecenter identifier and game app identifier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Ok, I have a game center bundle identifier and an app bundle identifier. One from iPhone developer website and other from iTunes connect. I need to make sure both get added into my app but how do i do it. My game center id is gamecenter101 and my app id is app101. I have to have both inside my info.plist in order for my app to work right. Any suggestions on how to do this? Is there some way I can use both of them?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on iTunes Connect? It answers this question in great detail.